# change json with html button

Tags: javascript, html, json

Hi I have this problem when I want to delete my json entries with a button in html. Right now I have a structure of `/data.json`, `/views/home.handlebars`, `/public/js/home.js`, `public/routes/home.js`, `etc`. I tried to define a function with a `<script>` tag, but it won't work since the console says `"data is not defined"`

Here is the `data.json`

```
{

"receipts": [

    {
        "receipt_ID": "1",
        "purchase_month": "2",
        "purchase_day": "12",
        "purchase_year": "2017",
        "seller": "Trader Joe's",
        "#_of_items": "3",
        "items_array": [ "1001", "1002", "1003" ],
        "imageURL": "",
        "uploader_ID": "Dominic",
        "note": "Dominic bought this at TJ",
        "deleted": "0"
    },

    {
        "receipt_ID": "2",
        "purchase_month": "2",
        "purchase_day": "10",
        "purchase_year": "2017",
        "seller": "Von's",
        "#_of_items": "2",
        "items_array": [ "2001", "2002" ],
        "imageURL": "",
        "uploader_ID": "Dominic",
        "note": "Dominic bought this at Vons",
        "deleted": "0"
    }
],

"item": [
        {
            "receipt_ID": "1",
            "item_index": "1",
            "item_ID": "1001",
            "item_catalog": "fruit",
            "item_name": "Apple",
            "item_imageURL": "/image/item_icon/apple.png",
            "expiration_month": "2",
            "expiration_day": "28",
            "expiration_year": "2017",
            "price_per_unit": "1.99",
            "unit": "lbs",
            "amount": "3.2",
            "total_price": "6.37",
            "shareable": true,
            "wasted": "0",
            "used_up": "0"
        },

        {
            "receipt_ID": "1",
            "item_index": "2",
            "item_ID": "1002",
            "item_catalog": "drink",
            "item_name": "Diet Coke",
            "item_imageURL": "/image/item_icon/drinks.png",
            "expiration_month": "8",
            "expiration_day": "31",
            "expiration_year": "2017",
            "price_per_unit": "0.99",
            "unit": "count",
            "amount": "5",
            "total_price": "4.95",
            "shareable": true,
            "wasted": "0",
            "used_up": "0"
        }]
    }
```

Here is the html function call, along with the `<script>` tag

```
<ul class="private_shelf">
  {{#each item}}
  <li herf="/item/{{item_ID}}" class="food">
    {{item_name}}
    <img src="{{item_imageURL}}" class="food_icon">
  </li>
  <button onclick="removeItem({{item_index}})">Remove Item</button> {{/each}}
</ul>

<script>
  function removeItem(cid) {
    console.log("removing");
    data.item.splice(cid, 1);
  }
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    //do stuff with your data here
  });
</script>
```

When I put the script part in `public/js/home.js`, the function calls properly (console displays `"removing"`), but it says data is not defined here and either is require() defined.

But when I put the function in `routes/home.js`, the function is not called at all.

How can I be able to delete the entry in `data.json` from a button in html and which file should the javascript function be in?

Thanks in advance.

Update:
[Here is my folder hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOcEE.png)

I'm doing `$.getJSON('/data.json', function(data){ data = data; });` right now, but the console still responds with "GET localhost:3000/data.json 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: You will need to use nodejs for this

Comment: where is your data object? a global var?

Comment: my data object is immediately in the root folder. So if the html is in /views/home.handlebars, json is in /data.json

Answer (score 0):

The variable data in not accessible in `removeItem` as variables are function scoped.

Try Creating a variable in parent scope so that is it accessible in `removeItem` function.

```
var data;

function removeItem(cid) {
  console.log("removing");
  if (data) {
    data.item.splice(cid, 1);
  } else {
    console.log("data is not fetched yet")
  }
}


$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
  //do stuff with your data here
  data = data;
});
```

**Depending on your js there could better ways of doing it but you can give this a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I see I missed declaring the variable first here. One more question: now the getJSON function is trying to fetch JSON file from localhost:3000/data.json, but it's not there.. Our file hierarchy looks like this:

Comment: root{ 
        public{
              css{}
              js{
                home.js
              }
              routes{
                home.js
              }
           }
        app.js
        data.json
}

Comment: it's immediately in the root folder

Comment: Then you can start path with `/` -> `'/data.json'` , because path that start with `/` are relative to root.

Comment: @FangYuxiao :  Did it help?

Comment: Sorry, I just got home, and it didn't help. I've updated my hierarchy in the post. Should I do it a different way?